# Зайти на сайт через прокси используя Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

Почему не заходит через прокси? заход есть но с моего месторасположения.

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
.................................................
//подключаемся к прокси
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArguments("188.18.52.137:8080");
IWebDriver Driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
Driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);                   
Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://pikimag.ru/");  //Переходим по URL
```

Answer (score 0):

тут немного Вы ошиблись с настройкой ChromeOptions

нужно либо в  AddArguments указывать `options.AddArguments("--proxy-server=http://user:password@188.18.52.137:8080")`(пропустить `user:password@`, если нет логина),
либо настроить ChromeOptions следующим образом.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
proxy = new Proxy();
proxy.Kind = ProxyKind.Manual;
proxy.IsAutoDetect = false;
proxy.HttpProxy =
proxy.SslProxy = "188.18.52.137:8080";
options.Proxy = proxy;
options.AddArgument("ignore-certificate-errors");
IWebDriver Driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: А как проверить есть подключение к прокси или нет?

Comment: А код проверялся? Просто я несколько лет назад потратил дня 3 что бы реализовать это, но оказалось что у хромдрайвера есть баг связанный с работой прокси который не фиксился пару лет. Чисто спортивный интерес -- пофиксили или нет)